# Angular 6 (click) not firing on quick tap in iOS browser

Tags: ios, angular

I have a button with (click) implemented as follows:

```
<button mat-button (click)="onTranslate()" title="Translate">
```

Which fires this function:

```
public onTranslate() {
    this.translate.emit();
}
```

The click/taps work properly on pc and android but very quick taps on iOS are not firing. Has anyone run into a similar issue? I have tested in iOS 11.4.1 and 12.0. The button appears below text upon that text being highlighted while the iOS copy, lookup buttons are visible.

Here is the code where the component is instantiated:

```
<div class="o-viewer-container">
<div #quillContainer>
</div>
<div #toolbar [hidden]="!showToolbar" [ngStyle]="toolbarStyle">
    <o-translate-toolbar (translate)="onTranslate()"></o-translate-toolbar>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might need to involve some help from 3rd party library such as hammerJS and build a supporting directive in your Angular project. Cuz a quick tap in iOS might not be recognised as a click event.